# Delete a specific item from Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

So I have an assignment that involves creating an imaginary memory manager in C++. Here are the instructions

Write a C++ program that emulate the operating system’s responsibility of allocating
memory to certain programs. This will be a very simple page-based view of memory
management. On startup, your program will have some 32 pages of contiguous, unused
memory. Each page will be 4 KB long

My problem is when it comes to deleting specific "programs" from the linked list. Here's my current DestroyProgram method

```
void DestroyProgram(string proName) { //Deletes
    Node* iterator = head;
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        if (iterator->programName == "FREE") {
            int count = 0;
            while (iterator != NULL && iterator->programName == "FREE") {
                iterator->programName = "FREE";
                iterator = iterator->nextProgram;

            }
            return;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            iterator = iterator->nextProgram;
        }
    }
    cout << iterator->programName << " is not there.";
}
```

If the memory is not being used it is labeled as FREE. So im trying to say if the programname equals what the user enters as the program name then it is deleted. I'm just confused as to why it isnt working

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The 7th line is unnecessary... `iterator->programName = "FREE";` , you already checked if it was FREE

Comment: we didn't see the type of `iterator->programName`. If it's `char *` and it doesn't work that's normal.

Comment: Where is the check for `iterator->programName == proName`? I can't see how you are identifying the entry to be deleted.

Comment: this entire function really has nothing with deleting stuff.. have you even ran it?

Comment: proName is not used in this function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here, but making these assumptions:
* your linked list contains all memory blocks managed by your Memory Manager
* if the node representing a memory block is free then programName is set to "FREE"
* if the  node is taken by a program then programName is set to the name of the program
* You don't actually delete any nodes, just relabel them as "FREE"

```
void DestroyProgram(string proName) { //Deletes
    Node* iterator = head;
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        if (iterator->programName == proName) {
            int count = 0;
            while (iterator != NULL && iterator->programName == proName) {
                iterator->programName = "FREE";
                iterator = iterator->nextProgram;
            }

            // If you return here, you're assuming that programs always have memory allocated in consecutive blocks
            // If they request memory more than once, the memory blocks may not be together
            // In that case, you have to keep searching through to the end of the list
            return;

            count++;
        }
        else {
            iterator = iterator->nextProgram;
        }
    }
    cout << proName << " is not there.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm just give you a generic version to delete a node from a linked list. You have to make three cases when deleting a node from a list.

> 1. If the list is empty
> 2. If the node you want to delete is head
> 3. If the node is anywhere else

```
void DestroProgram(string proName) //Deletes
  {
    Node *iterator = head;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
    cout << "List is empty" << endl;
    }
    else if(iterator->programName == proName)
    {
       head = head->nextProgram   //point to your new head
       delete iterator;    //delete your old head
    }
    else
    {
       Node *previousNode = head;
       while(head != NULL)
       {
         if(iterator->programName == proName)
         {
          previousNode->next = iterator->next  //make the new connection between nodes
          delete iterator
         }
          previousNode = iterator;  //sets previousNode one node behind iterator
          iterator = iterator->nextProgram;
        }
     }
  }
```